# Using powershell to find files that match two seperate regular expressions

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-2.0

I want to find any file that can match two regular expressions, for example all files that have at least one of `bat`, `hat`, `cat` *as well as* the word `noun`. That would be any file that can match both regular expressions `[bhc]at` and `noun`.

The regex parameter to `select-string` only seems to work on a line-by-line basis. It seems you can pass in multiple patterns delimited by commas (`select-string -pattern "[bhc]at","noun"`) but it matches either, rather than both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merging @mjolinor's single get-content with @JNK's optimised filtering gives:

```
dir | ?{ [string](gc $_) | ?{$_ -match "[bhc]at"} | ?{$_ -match "noun"} }
```

If you don't mind the repetition, you can pipe the results to select string to view the contexts of these matches:

```
    | select-string -pattern "[bhc]at","noun" -allmatches
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't need both get-contents? The second match appears to work against the filename.

Answer (score 5):

You can always just use two filters:

```
dir | ? {(gc $_) -match '[bhc]at'} | ?{(gc $_) -match 'noun'}
```

This just gets all the objects that match the first criteria, and checks that result set for the second.  I imagine it would be quicker than checking both as well since a lot of files will only get checked once, then filtered out.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a one that only requires one get-content:

```
dir | where-object{[string](get-content $_)|%{$_ -match "[bhc]at" -and $_ -match "noun"}}
```

Comment: Your solution works only if `[bhc]at` and `noun` are on the same line.

Comment: Casting (get-content $_) to [sting] makes it all the same line.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with the rather cumbersome-but-working:

```
dir | where-object{((get-content $_) -match "[bhc]at") -and ((get-content $_) -match "noun")}
```

I can shorten this with aliases, but is there a more elegant way, preferably with less keystrokes?

My other option, if this becomes a frequent problem, seems to be making a new commandlet for the above snippet.